# Ventura > Settings > Sound doesn't let me change output or input

Tags: audio, ventura, microphone

[image: sound output settings]
[image: sound input settings]

It is stuck on the options that you see here.

When I plug in an external mic (not shown here), I see a new row in "Input" called "USB Audio Device" (underneath "Unknown USB Audio Device"), but I can't choose it.

How can I fix this?